# How to Deal with 'Impute" data type after treating missing values with Hmisc in R

Tags: r, data-science, missing-data, hmisc

I used Hmisc package to impute my missing values and after replacing back in data frame i noticed that my variable types has changed in some "impute" type which is not recognised by many algorithms and i can not feed my data.
I want to get rid of this 'Impute' type of variable class and change my variable classes to back to normal data types like factors and integer.
already tried as.factors and as.integerbut nothing happened.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))` so that we can verify our solutions on your data ?

Comment: @RonakShah since it was too long i have updated in my question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `type.convert` which would convert the data to appropriate classes automatically.

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

There is also `type_convert` in `readr` which works in similar way.

```
readr::type_convert(df)
```